# ¿Cómo crear un archivo .txt a partir de una tabla en SQL Server en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

yo tengo una Query que me genera una tabla con varias columnas y necesito que generar un .txt a partir de la tabla y no encuentro un ejemplo claro para realizarlo ya que quiero hacerlo desde sql server seria de ayuda una sugerencia

Ejemplo del codigo pero solo funciona con un columna alguna idea de adaptación a varias columnas

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(1000)
--Separador ;
SELECT @Text = COALESCE(@Text + ';', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 
[Columnas])
FROM [Tabla]

SET @Cmd = 'echo ' + @Text + ' >C:{Direccion de salida} Salida.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @Cmd
```

Comment: puedes conectar excel a la base de datos y una vez que hagas la carga de la data la guardas como csv

Comment: Aunque lo parezca, en ésta comunidad no se suelen realizar las tareas de nadie si no demuestra su implicación en el trabajo. Para ello te recomiendo copiar el código relacionado con la pregunta y pegarlo como texto una vez editada tu pregunta. Un saludo